# Using Angular to get names from the Google People API

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I hate to ask for help on such a simple problem but I've been at it for hours and I cannot figure it out.

The function on my service page is:

```
  async getPeople() {
    const mypeople = await gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
      resourceName: 'people/me',
      personFields: 'names,emailAddresses',
    })
    this.peopleItems = mypeople.result.connections;
    console.log(this.peopleItems);    
  }
```

The date returned to the console looks like this:

```
0:
  emailAddresses: [{…}]
    etag: "%EgcBAj0JPjcuGgwBAgMEBQYHCAkKCwwiDGdncXcxTC9iTTJZPQ=="
  names: Array(1)
   0:
      displayName: "Mr. Russo"
      displayNameLastFirst: "Russo, Mr."
      familyName: "Russo"
      honorificPrefix: "Mr."
    metadata: {primary: true, source: {…}}
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
    resourceName: "people/c7626061877818240014"
 __proto__: Object
```

The class in my component page is as follows:

```
export class PeopleComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

My problem is I am unable to display the contact names on the component html page with the following example.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of auth.peopleItems">
    <h3>{{ item.names }}</h3>
</div>
```

But my browser displays:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another nested **`ngFor`** inorder to access displayName and so on as item.names is an array,

```
<div *ngFor="let item of auth.peopleItems">
  <div *ngFor="let itemObj of item.names">
    <h3>{{itemObj.displayName}}</h3>
  </dvi>
</div>
```